# Saving data into files and reload them later

Tags: c#, wpf, save

I am working on a WPF project with C#.
There is a `MainWindow` and some other windows showing some data. I have also three XML files, where data from lists can be saved. The code is all written and works perfect.

Now my question is, how to save the whole file. I want to have the capability to, for example, save all the data into files, and user can open these files later and load the data into lists, and commence working, where they left the application before.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Have you got some code of what you have tried so far for us to look at?

Comment: I have not tried to handle this yet, because I have no idea how to do it.  have searched some time on the Internet, but I didn't found something useful for me.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you need to do it with following steps: 1. save your XML files with a specific extension name. 2. link the default extension name to your application (so it will be opened by your application by default) 3. Open/read the file with XML content from your application. [Check this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avip/archive/2008/10/27/wpf-supporting-command-line-arguments-and-file-extensions.aspx)  4. Deserialize XML into items and display them in your list.

Comment: I think, you got it. It is like you creat e.g. a word Project and save it, you are able to open it again and work on. That's what I want. So I hve to save the XML to a completely other location?

Comment: You don't want to open every XML by your application, so you need to save XML into an extension name that is specific to your application. Then you can tell Windows to always open this type of file by your application.

Comment: What do I do if there are two relevant XMLs for one project? Should I write all the data in one?

Comment: You can create one link file to link to these files, and then just open the link file by your application, I have posted a answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to do it with following steps:

1. Save your XML files with a specific extension name.

   you can achieve this by many ways: e.g. you can save your actual XML files into a location, and then just create a link file that contents links to these files. Or you can ZIP all the XML files into one single file.
2. link the default extension name to your application (so it will be opened by your application by default)
3. Open/read the file with XML content from your application.

   [Check this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avip/archive/2008/10/27/wpf-supporting-command-line-arguments-and-file-extensions.aspx)
4. Deserialize XML into items and display them in your list.

Comment: How do I save the data of two lists in one file? I mean how do I seperate These two?

Comment: @gillesberger_p, as I said in my answer, you can just save them into separate files as you already did. Just create another file with a specific extension (e.g. mydata.extension) contents paths of these files (e.g. C:\Myfolder\list1.xml; C:\Myfolder\list2.xml). Then you can open this link file in your program, and work from there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how can I read the file I've already opened. I mean, I even don't know the path of it.

Comment: @gillesberger_p, I'm a bit confused, you said you are able to save the data into XML files, and now you are saying you don't know the path?

Comment: Yes, I know how to save it, but if I display a save file Dialog and save mydata.Extension to let's say the Desktop. What happens, when the user chenges the path and copies it to documents or renames it. So I don't know, where it is saved. And I think that I Need the path and Name for Filestream.

Comment: @gillesberger_p, still don't understand. say you have 3 files now: mydata.Extension; list1.xml; list2.xml. Your application can save list1.xml and list2.xml into a safe location and with read-only attribute, and only expose mydata.extension to the user. so no matter where the mydata.extension file is, when use double clicked on it, your application can open it and know where list1.xml and list2.xml is.

Comment: @gillesberger_p, and as I said in my answer, if you find this is not suitable, you can zip/achieve the data files and the link file into a single file, just like what Microsoft did for docx for example.